# First popup wont close when next popup is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, html, popup

I am wanting the popups to only appear one at a time, no matter how many popups there are. So if one popup is currently open, it will close and the new one would remain open. I currently have them coded so the initial link will open and close the popup, and the user should be able to click anywhere in the document to close the popup after it has been opened.

I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hdotseth/M4NWQ/).

Problems I'm having with this code:

1.The first popup clicked wont disappear if another is selected
2.You have to double click the link to make the popup reappear if you click anywhere besides the inital link to close it
3.All the popups should be initially closed

**HTML:**

```
<div id="link"><a href="#" class="showPopup" rel="one"> One</a></div>
<div class="popup popup_hide" id="one">Content</div>

<div id="link"> <a href="#" class="showPopup" rel="two"> Two</a></div>
<div class="popup popup_hide" id="two">Content <a href="#">link</a></div>

<div id="link"> <a href="#" class="showPopup" rel="three"> Three</a></div>
<div class="popup popup_hide" id="three">Content <a href="#"></a></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var popupStatus = 0;

if (popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        $('.showPopup').click(function () {
            $('#' + $(this).attr('rel') + '_img').removeClass('border_grey');
            if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).hide();
                $(this).removeClass("selected");
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                $('#' + $(this).attr('rel') + '_img').addClass('border_grey');
                $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
                popupStatus = 1; 
            }

         return false;
        });

    }
 else if (popupStatus == 1){
         $('.popup').hide();
         popupStatus = 0;
    }

    $('.hide_popup').click(function () {
        $('img').removeClass('border_grey');
        $('.popup').hide();
        return false;
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (e.target.class !== 'popup_hide') {
            $('.popup_hide').hide();
        }
    });
```

}); // jQuery End

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do what you are looking for:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M4NWQ/2/)</kbd>

```
var rr, popupStatus = 0;

$('.popup').hide();

$('.showPopup').click(function (e) {
    rr = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.popup').hide();
    $('#' + rr).show();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.class !== 'popup_hide' && e.target.class !== 'showPopup') {
        $('.popup_hide').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing to mention is, that you should rework your html, because it is containing Id's with the same name, which should not be, because an element Id should be unique.

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but I updated your code a little, so this could be some starting point for you

HTML

```
<div id="link1"> 
    <a href="#" class="showPopup" rel="popup_brain"> hello</a>
</div>
<div class="popup popup_hide" id="popup_brain">Content</div>
<div id="link2"> <a href="#" class="showPopup" rel="heart"> Goodbye</a> 
</div>
<div class="popup popup_hide" id="heart">Content <a href="#">hi</a></div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $('.popup_hide').hide()

  $('#link1').click(function(){
          $('#popup_brain').show()
          $('#heart').hide()
  })

  $('#link2').click(function(){
          $('#heart').show()
          $('#popup_brain').hide()
  })

})
```

Best

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using the ids because they are going to change depending on the page and application. I was hoping to keep it within the class so it could be used anywhere.

Comment: ah ok, did not know this, but there is already an answer which fits :)